# How to compare Date in SQlite?

Tags: sqlite, date

How to compare dates which stored as String in Sqlite Database and fetch data...?

I am storing date in a format DD.MM.YY

I have tried  <= but it is working. And I want to compare only Date and not Time. So I am passing value as dd.mm.yy

I have tried 
"Select SUM(tramount) as s From mytrans where accno = " + acno + " AND trdate <= Datetime( '"+date+"' )" this too,but it is not working.

Comment: You should be storing them as `YYYY-MM-DD` then you can compare them without problems. You can't reliably compare dates that are stored as `DD.MM.YY`

Comment: thanks..!  But is there any way to compare dates which are in format dd.mm.yy